# How to scroll a node across a screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nodes, game-physics

This is going to sound like a really simple question but I'm new to Xcode and could not for the life of me figure out to do this correctly, I was wondering what a good way to repeatedly spawn nodes on the left side of the screen and scroll them to the right side of the screen. It's just for decoration so they don't need need to do anything else. The problem is when I tried to scroll the nodes across the screen it took my background with it. The background is put in with the following code-

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

        SKSpriteNode *bgImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"start"];
        [bgImage setScale: .52];
        bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:bgImage];
```

edit: This is how I moved the nodes-

```
- (void)moveObstacle
{
    NSArray *nodes = self.children;

    for(SKNode * node in nodes){
        if (![node.name  isEqual: @"start"] && ![node.name  isEqual: @"start"]) {
            SKSpriteNode *ob = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
            CGPoint obVelocity = CGPointMake(-OBJECT_VELOCITY, 0);
            CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(obVelocity,_dt);

            ob.position = CGPointAdd(ob.position, amtToMove);
         }
    }
}
```

But the only problem is that a separate text button moves along with it when it is supposed to remain static.

I just don't know how to keep this from moving with my other nodes.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for an `SKEmitterNode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run appropriate `SKAction` on it:

```
SKAction *move1 = [SKAction moveByX:bgImage.size.width y:0 duration:5.0];
SKAction *move2 = [SKAction moveToX:-bgImage.size.width y:0 duration:0.0];
[bgImage runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[move1,move2]]]];
```

Comment: I probably didn't phrase that correctly, my problem isn't so much how to move a node, as it is to spawn a mass of nodes repeatedly, and move them across.

Comment: That worked perfectly, it took me awhile because I was thinking of the answer in terms of what the background was doing instead of what the moving nodes were, Thanks!